# C3js stacked bar chart with multiple pieces of data for each bar section

Tags: javascript, bar-chart, c3.js, stacked-chart

I'm trying to create a stacked bar chart where each bar section in a group will have two pieces of data, a count and a cost. I want the count to be reflected in the bar, and I want the cost to be displayed in the bar label.

I'd also like to be able to display both the count and the cost in the tooltip.

Is this possible, and what is the easiest way to do it?

Comment: Just to be sure I understand, you do only want to display the count as a bar chart, am I right?

Comment: Yes, the length of the bar segments should be based on the count. The label should show the cost. I did already do this since I posted this by saving the cost information in an external variable and referencing it in the Label Format function and editing the HTML of the tooltip. But is there any built in way that's easier?

Answer (score 1):

This is what you might want:

```
var matrix = [
  {//cat1 - position 0
    Low: {  cost: 10, count: 2},
    Medium: {  cost: 100, count: 20},
     High: {  cost: 1000, count: 40}
  },
  {//cat2 - position 1
    Low: {  cost: 20, count: 4},
    Medium: {  cost: 200, count: 40},
     High: {  cost: 2000, count: 60}
  },
   {//cat3 - position 2
    Low: {  cost: 30, count: 6},
    Medium: {  cost: 300, count: 60},
     High: {  cost: 3000, count: 80}
  }];
//countsData can be build using matrix
var countsData = [
            ['Low', 2, 4, 6],
            ['Medium', 20, 40, 60],
            ['High', 40, 60, 80],
        ];

var riskToColor = {
            Low: '#9ACD32',
            Medium: '#FFD700',
            High: '#FF4500'
        };
var categoriesList = ['cat1', 'cat2', 'cat3'];

var chart = c3.generate({
  bindto: '#cool-chart',
  size: {
    height: 200
    },
    data: {
        columns: countsData,
        type: 'bar',
        colors: riskToColor,
        groups: [
            ['Low', 'Medium', 'High']
        ],
       order: null,
       labels: {                       
         format: function (v, id, i, j) {
           if(i !== undefined) {
             // console.log(i+" " + matrix[i][id]['cost']); 
             return matrix[i][id]['cost'] + "$";
           } 
           else return v;
         }},
      },
      axis: {
         rotated: true,
         x: {
          type: 'category',
          categories: categoriesList
         },
        y: {show: false}
       },
      tooltip: {
        contents: function (d) {
          var $$ = this, config = $$.config,text;
          console.log(d[0]);
          text = "<table class='" + $$.CLASS.tooltip + "'><tr><th colspan='3'>"+categoriesList[d[0].index]+"</th></tr>"; 
          text += "<tr class='" + $$.CLASS.tooltipName + "'>";
          text += "<td class='name'>Risk</td>";
          text += "<td class='name'>Count</td>";
          text += "<td class='value'>Cost</td></tr>";
          for (i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {
            text += "<tr class='" + $$.CLASS.tooltipName + "'>";
            text += "<td class='name'><span style='background-color:"+riskToColor[d[i].name]+"'></span>"+d[i].name+"</td>";
            text += "<td class='value'>"+d[i].value+"</td>";
            text += "<td class='value'>"+matrix[d[i].x][d[i].name]['cost']+"$</td></tr>";
           }
          return text + "</table>";
        }
     }
});
```

`Codepen link` https://codepen.io/georgebuzoianu/pen/djoMKR

You have to build an additional structure where to keep the whole matrix (category-cost-count). Using that matrix you will be able to add the corresponding cost label for each count data.

Answer (score 0):

I think a better workaround would be to use the custom XY Bar Chart (see https://c3js.org/samples/axes_x_tick_format.html). Here, you will define the X Axis with your set of data directly with the c3.js library.

For example, for your data, you can customize your own X axis, with something like this:

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        x: 'cost',
        columns: [
            ['cost', 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60],
            ['count', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250],
        ],
        type: 'bar',
    },
});
```

Comment: I'm already defining the x axis from my own data, and it's non-numerical data (axis.x.type='category'). The count and cost are both under that. The different blocks in the stack are another piece of information. Like this: https://imgur.com/CNjVFJg

Comment: Ah ok. You didn't mention you already used categories so I proposed the lightest and the easiest. And I think you found the easiest way since the library doesn't really support this :-)